# prev/next navigation in detail view of news (tx_news) TYPO3 Extension

Tags: typo3, tx-news

I wonder how to build a prev/next navigation in detail known from tt_news.
Is there no build in way in news extension? Any ideas?

Comment: Which extension? `news` or the older `tt_news`? You mention both in your question.

Comment: news (tx_news) - I mentioned tt_news because there its build in the way I need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if u meen the tx_news / news plz look here in the example:
https://github.com/TYPO3-extensions/news/blob/master/Classes/ViewHelpers/SimplePrevNextViewHelper.php

Answer (score 4):

I updated the SimplePrevNextViewHelper for the next release of version 5.0.0.
You can get it at https://github.com/TYPO3-extensions/news/blob/master/Classes/ViewHelpers/SimplePrevNextViewHelper.php. Either override the existing one or copy it to an own extension and use it from there.